# Cardano marketplace that allows selling a batch of NFTs

Tags: smart-contract, nft, policy, asset

anyone aware of a cardano marketplace that allows us to mint NFTs in batches that will launch with smart contracts launch or at least close to the launch? So e.g. 1 policy ID, 10000 asset names that is available for sale for a week - something like this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can publish multiple NFTs at once in the following marketplaces:

- [CNFT.io](https://cnft.io/)
- [Tokhun](https://tokhun.io/)